# how to change class of a element multiple times in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Function in vanilla js, which I want to implement in Vue.js

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xjk3xqnprw
This is what I want to implement in Vue js

Below is my vue component, it is loading perfectly but it is not having animation

My Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dice Game <h5 class="blink" style="color: red">* live</h5></div>
                    <div class="card-body" style="background-color: #3f0d12;background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #3f0d12 0%, #a71d31 74%);
">
                        <div class="dice">
                            <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                            <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                    <span class="dot"></span>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Home",
        methods: {
            rollDice() {
                const array1= [5,6];
                const dice = [...document.querySelectorAll(".die-list")];
                console.log(dice);
                let count = 0;
                dice.forEach(die => {
                    toggleClasses(die);
                    die.dataset.roll = array1[count];
                    count++
                });
            },
            toggleClasses(die) {
                die.classList.toggle("odd-roll");
                die.classList.toggle("even-roll");
            },
            getRandomNumber(min, max) {
                min = Math.ceil(min);
                max = Math.floor(max);
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            },
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.rollDice();
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I want the toggle style class(in a loop) so that the animation of dice roll can be achieved

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Can you create a `jsFiddle` or `codepen` with your code? It would help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now toggling your `rollDice` function beforeMount, if you change this to `created` the changes will be toggled correctly, also note that you will need to change `toggleClasses` to `this.toggleClasses` since it is defined in the methods section of your component and is therefore bound to the component and not a global function anymore.

I hope this helps you!

P.S. [See my codepen](https://codepen.io/svenh98/pen/MWweMzW) for a working sample, note that I used a settimeout here for demo purposes, but you can adjust this to a `@click="rollDice"` on a button within your component and leave out the mounted alltogether

Comment: I used the code with SetInterval and when I do so the 1st dice don't roll in every odd time

Comment: @VanshTah it specifies Vue where to bind on the DOM as described here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el